# PHP MySQL short query assoc code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I need to query and assoc many queries like this

```
<?php 
$datacenter=mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
```

db connection, now we count how many voted option 1 and 2 and 3

```
 $r11=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total1` 
FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` = '1' ");
    $r11r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r11);


    $r12=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total2` 
FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` = '2'");
    $r12r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r12);

    $r13=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total3` 
FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` = '3'");
    $r13r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r13);
    ?>
```

now we echo the result to display how many voted option 1, 2 and 3

```
<?php echo number_format($r11r['total1'],0,',','.'); ?>
<? php echo number_format($r12r['total2'],0,',','.'); ?>
<? php echo number_format($r13r['total3'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

Is there any way to make this code shorter ? I am new to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach(array(1,2,3) as $firstvote){
  $res=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total` 
                                  FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` = '$firstvote' ");
  $r[$firstvote]=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
 }

foreach($r as $set){
  echo number_format($set['total'],0,',','.'); 
}
```

High vote only:

```
$r['total']=0;
foreach(array(1,2,3) as $firstvote){
  $res=mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total` 
                                  FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` = '$firstvote' ");
  $tmp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  $r=max($tmp['total'],$r['total']);
 }


 echo number_format($r,0,',','.');
```

since i dont now what you really want to do, this is a solution to get only the highest value of all results. But you should do this iwth your SQL query. add something like `ORDER BY total LIMIT 1`

Comment: This answer is good, how to do if I only want to display the result with higher votes only ? Example option 3 has 78 result, option 2 has 204 results and option 1 has 24 results. Then I would like to display only the result of option 2 because is the higher voted with 204 votes

Comment: It show error in line for(array(1,2,3) as $firstvote){

Comment: @caradevineros OH typo change `for` to `foreach` updated the answer

Comment: ok this give me the total amount of votes of the most voted. I need to show the name of the most ranked now, it could be option 1 or 2 or 3. Any idea?

Comment: In this query the most ranked is value 2 with 47 votes

Comment: `since i dont now what you really` , i cant edit my answer step by step after you ask new stuff here, sorry.

Comment: @caradevineros One question per question please. Dragging someone down the `and now.... and now` ___rabbit hole___ is not the right thing to do. If you have another question ask another question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` in your query:

```
SELECT 
  firstvote,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM votes
GROUP BY firstvote
```

And you reach all unique `firstvote`and rows count with this value.
If you want select values only for this `firstvote` you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
  firstvote,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM votes
WHERE firstvote IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY firstvote
```

For sorting values by count you can use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT 
  firstvote,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM votes
GROUP BY firstvote
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 3
```

`DESC` means bigger at first.

Comment: I was a little bit to slow again ;-)

Comment: This answer is good, how to do if I only want to display the result with higher votes only ? Example option 3 has 78 result, option 2 has 204 results and option 1 has 24 results. Then I would like to display only the result of option 2 because is the higher voted with 204 votes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CASE syntax for that and do it all in one query

```
$sql = "SELECT
            SUM(CASE WHEN `firstvote` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total1,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `firstvote` = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN `firstvote` = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total3
        FROM `votes`";

$res = mysqli_query($datacenter, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

echo number_format($row['total1'],0,',','.');
echo number_format($row['total2'],0,',','.');
echo number_format($row['total3'],0,',','.');
```

This will return 3 columns called `total1` `total2` and `total3` in a single result row

Comment: This answer is good, how to do if I only want to display the result with higher votes only ? Example option 3 has 78 result, option 2 has 204 results and option 1 has 24 results. Then I would like to display only the result of option 2 because is the higher voted with 204 votes

Comment: You can do that using some simple PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT COUNT(firstvote) AS `total1` FROM `votes` WHERE `firstvote` in ('1','2','3') GROUP BY firstvote");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo number_format($row['total1'], 0, ',', '.');
}
```

Comment: This answer is good, how to do if I only want to display the result with higher votes only ? Example option 3 has 78 result, option 2 has 204 results and option 1 has 24 results. Then I would like to display only the result of option 2 because is the higher voted with 204 votes