# join mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_assoc in single $query

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Is it possible to make shorter the follow code as a single $var ?
What I want is to put mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_assoc in the same single $query

```
    <?php 
    $datacenter=mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','db');
    $query=mysqli_query - mysqli_fetch_assoc($datacenter, "SELECT 
COUNT(pool_1) AS result FROM votes WHERE `answer` = '1'");
    ?>
```

So I can then display echo it like this

```
<?php echo number_format($query['result'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

Can that be done?

Comment: `$query = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($datacenter, "SELECT 
COUNT(pool_1) AS result FROM votes WHERE answer = '1'"));`

Comment: I would suggest concentrating on code working properly rather than trying to make it unreadable. It may be you that is asked to amend this script in 6 months.

Comment: Any suggest Riggs ? and thanks Artem

Comment: Yes, dont try and run to many instructions together. Example if the `mysqli_query()` fails how easy will it be to log that error? Almost impossible using the code you are trying to write

Comment: Also I have no idea what that minus sign is doing in your example

Comment: yet alone the jquery tag; the code is incomplete also.

Comment: this also looks like a repost of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026038/php-mysql-pool-show-highest-voted-and-votes but only reduced in this one.

Comment: O and @ArtemIlchenko suggestion is pretty dangerous as that would just return the first row into `$query`. Works if only one row will be returned but wont if you are getting 2 or more rows back in your resultset

Comment: Yea, I think its different questions about the same code really @Fred-ii- like this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020032/php-mysql-short-query-assoc-code Although he does not seem to have used any of the previous answer provided in this code